# Split a Set into multiple Sets by Class

Tags: java, split, set

*Apologies if this has been answered elsewhere, but I have yet to find a good answer!*

---

I have a `Set` of objects that I need to split by their underlying `class` type, into a `Set` for each (obviously this means that each object in the initial set will only appear in *one* of the new `Set` objects).

My current approach to this is as follows:

```
public static Map<Class,Set<Foo>> splitByClass(Set<Foo> foos) {

    // Create a map for the result
    Map<Class,Set<Foo>> FooMap = new HashMap<Class,Set<Foo>>();

    for (Foo foo: foos) {
        Class type = foo.getClass();

        // If a set for this key exists, add the item to that.
        if (FooMap.containsKey(type)) {
            FooMap.get(type).add(foo);
        } else {
            // Otherwise make a new set, add the item and the set to the map.
            Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<Foo>();
            set.add(foo);
            FooMap.put(type, set);
        }
    }        
    return FooMap;
}
```

**My question:** Is there a more generic way to split a `Set` into subsets, based on some evaluation method such as checking Class type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a Guava [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html), it will make life a lot simpler:

```
Multimap<Class<? extends Foo>, Foo> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
for (Foo foo : foos) {
    mmap.put(foo.getClass(), foo);
}
return mmap;
```

This code is pretty much equivalent to your above code, except that you must change the return type to `Multimap<Class<? extends Foo>, Foo>`.

And here's a generic version that works with any supplied interface type:

```
public static <X> Multimap<Class<X>, X> splitByClass(
    final Iterable<? extends X> implementations, final Class<X> interfaceType) {

    final Multimap<Class<X>, X> mmap = HashMultimap.create();
    for (final X implementation : implementations) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        // this should be safe:
        final Class<X> implementationType = (Class<X>) implementation.getClass();
        mmap.put(implementationType, implementation);
    }
    return mmap;
}
```

Comment: Agree, so long as you don't need the **Set-based** filtering in the question's solution.

Comment: @JohnB HashMultimap uses HashSet internally, so this should be equivalent

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting alternative for me to consider. I'll leave the question open for now, just in case anyone else wants to contribute an answer. If not, I'll accept yours in the near future :)